# How to send date from web to lead to datefield salesforce

Tags: html, date, inputfield, web2lead

I try to pass a date from a web2lead form to a date field, but the field stays empty.

```
Travel date in: <span class="dateInput dateOnlyInput">
 <input  id="00N1t00000K2yXV" name="00N1t00000K2yXV" size="12" type="date" />
</span>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=setting_up_web-to-lead.htm&type=5):

> The format for date and currency fields captured online is taken from your organization’s default settings - Default Locale and Currency Locale.

Make sure you're using the same format as your org (e.g. if using US, it would be 1/31/2019, other places would be 2019.01.31 or some other format).

Comment: When using the date field this already uses the same format but this still does not update/fills the fields

Comment: @Thomas Again, double-check your locale. It's been a while since I've used w2l personally, but I've never had an issue with it.